# MVC Postal Emailer Conflicting With Mvc.Unity4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container, postal

I'm experiencing a weird issue when attempting to use Postal within an MVC application that also uses Mvc.Unity4.

I believe the issue is thrown due to lacking access to the `HttpContext`.

I attempt to send the email from inside one of my Controllers using Postal:

```
dynamic e = new Email("AccountActivation");
e.To = "name@email.com"
e.Send();
```

Attempting to send an email results in the following exception within `Unity.Mvc4.UnityDependencyResolver`:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Unity.Mvc4.UnityDependencyResolver.get_ChildContainer() +57
   Unity.Mvc4.UnityDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType) +241
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultViewPageActivator.Create(ControllerContext controllerContext, Type type) +87
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +216
   Postal.EmailViewRenderer.RenderView(IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ControllerContext controllerContext, ImageEmbedder imageEmbedder) +182
   Postal.EmailViewRenderer.Render(Email email, String viewName) +204
   Postal.EmailService.CreateMailMessage(Email email) +72
   Postal.EmailService.Send(Email email) +65
```

I'm not too familiar with Mvc.Unity4, as this was added by a different developer.

Grasping at straws, I did try to register the correct Postal types within the Application_Start.  The initialization of the Unity container is occurring in `Bootstrapper.cs`:

```
container.RegisterType<UsersController>(new InjectionConstructor());
container.RegisterInstance<IEmailService>(new EmailService());
```

Within my controller, I have:

```
private IEmailService _emailService;
public UsersController()
{
    _emailService = new Postal.EmailService();
}

public UsersController(Postal.EmailService emailService)
{
    _emailService = emailService;
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SendEmail(EmailViewModel viewModel)
{
     dynamic e = new Email("AccountActivation");
     e.ViewData.Add("To", "name@email.com");
     e.ViewData.Add("From", "no-reply@email.com");
     _emailService.Send(e);

     More code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your suspicion is right. `HttpContext` is not available during application initialization. Therefore Postal will not work (because it relies on `ControllerContext` and `ViewContext`) in the `Application_Start` event.

Since you are using DI, this also extends to the constructor of every class that is configured using Unity - you cannot use Postal in the constructor, but can in methods that are called after `Application_Start` is complete.

You need to move the call to Postal outside of `Application_Start` or else use the native .NET mail libraries in this one case (because they rely on System.Net and have no dependencies on `HttpContext`).

Comment: Just to clarify, my call to create and send the Postal email does reside in a controller outside of Application_Start.  I was only attempting to register the Postal objects within the Application_Start, with the emailing code inside a controller, after Application_Start has run.

Comment: Please post the relevent DI configuration for postal and all its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I was finally able to get this working.

Once I removed the `async` from the method, everything began working as expected.

So by changing...

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SendEmail(EmailViewModel viewModel)
```

To this...

```
public ActionResult SendEmail(EmailViewModel viewModel)
```

I was then able to send the emails without triggering the exception inside `Unity.Mvc4.UnityDependencyResolver.get_ChildContainer()`.

I'm not sure why I wasn't able to call Postal's `.Send()` from within an `async` method (side note, I tried to call `.SendAsync()` with the same Unity issue resulting).  If anyone can shed some light on why this would work within an `async` method, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.